# Why in non autonomous ODE, the flow is $\varphi ^{t,t_0}(x_0)$ (i.e. depend on $t_0$)?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $\dot x=f(x)$ an autonomous ODE. Then the flow is simply defined as $$\varphi ^t(x_0)=x(t)$$ where $x_0=x(t_0)$. In particular, it's the trajectory of the solution that start at $x(t_0)$.

Now, if it's not autonomous, i.e. the ODE is $\dot x(t)=f(x(t),t)$, then the flow is $$x(t)=\varphi ^{t,t_0}(x_0).$$

Why do we need $t_0$ here ? It looks that $x(t)=\varphi ^{t}(x_0)$ looks fine, isn't it ?

Comment: Try this for, e.g., $x'(t)=t+x$, $x_0=0$, for two trajectories starting respectively at $t_0=-1$ and $t_0=1$.

Comment: In the autonomous case, you should take $t_0=0$, otherwise the definition doesn't make sense ($\phi^t$ means “follow the flow for $t$ units of time”, not “for $t-t_0$ units of times where $t_0$ can be anything”).

Comment: In the first case $x(t)=e^t\int_1^t ue^{-u}du$ and in the second case $x(t)=e^t\int_{-1}^t ue^{-u}du$... hummm very strange that changing the $t_0$ gives an other solution since I thought that given $x(t_0)$, the solution is unique (since $f(x,t)=x+t$ is Lipschtz wrt $x$). So the solution is not unique ?! @user10354138